# PyPDF2 ignores content, gets watermark only

Tags: python, pypdf

I have thousands of PDF files like [this one](https://www.docdroid.net/UeDNhd8/decisao-10166720039201098.pdf).

I'm trying to use PyPDF2 to convert them to plain text (code is below). But PyPDF2 apparently only "sees" the watermarks, not the content itself. What could I do here?

```
import os
import PyPDF2

path_to_pdfs = '/path/to/pdf/files/'
for filename in os.listdir(path_to_pdfs):
    if '.pdf' in filename.lower():
        with open(path_to_pdfs + filename, mode = 'rb') as f:
            txt = ''
            pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
            num_pages = pdf_reader.numPages
            for page in range(num_pages):
                page_obj = pdf_reader.getPage(page)
                page_text = page_obj.extractText()
                txt = txt + '\n' + page_text
            print(txt)
```

I'm using Python 3.5.1 and PyPDF2 1.26.0 on macOS 10.13.14.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes [pdfminer3k](https://github.com/jaepil/pdfminer3k) gives better results. Please check out "[How to read pdf file using pdfminer3k?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024697/how-to-read-pdf-file-using-pdfminer3k)"

I've tested the following code and it extracts text. However, the extraction is not 100% accurate...

```
# Open the example file
fp = open('Decisao_10166720039201098.pdf', 'rb')

from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser, PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox, LTTextLine

parser = PDFParser(fp)
doc = PDFDocument()
parser.set_document(doc)
doc.set_parser(parser)
doc.initialize('')
rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
laparams = LAParams()
laparams.char_margin = 1.0
laparams.word_margin = 1.0
device = PDFPageAggregator(rsrcmgr, laparams=laparams)
interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
extracted_text = ''

for page in doc.get_pages():
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    layout = device.get_result()
    for lt_obj in layout:
        if isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextBox) or isinstance(lt_obj, LTTextLine):
            extracted_text += lt_obj.get_text()

print(extracted_text)
```

Answer (score 0):

**PyPDF2** is good for normal PDF files. But I recommend you to use `pdfminer`. You can install it with `pip install pdfminer.six`
And Follow these Command:

```
from pdfminer import high_level # High level text extraction

local_pdf_filename = "path/to/your/pdf/file.pdf"
pages = [0] # Page which you wanna extract

extracted_text = high_level.extract_text(local_pdf_filename, "", pages)
print(extracted_text)
input('\n\nExtraction Complete')
```