# PyPDF2 extract empty Text

Tags: python, pypdf

I am using PyPDF2 for extract text from pdf.  All examples which I found in the google look like my code:

```py
import PyPDF2

reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("test2.pdf")
page = reader.getPage(0)
text = page.extractText()
print(text.encode("utf-8"))
```

However, I have empty text in my console:

> b''

This code I have tested for different pdf and all pdf's were empty

UPD:

```
# getDocumentInfo
{'/Producer': 'Skia/PDF m75'}
```

File [pdf](https://dropmefiles.com/eRpmc)

Comment: Does you pdf files contain really text, or maybe it is some kind of scanned image? Could you attach here file sample?

Comment: Refer to this answer, it might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/51328080/6234311

Comment: @kosist yes, pdf contains really text. I have added a pdf file

Comment: Did you try others libraries? Because even on github, there is written that sometimes this lib does not extract text properly...

Comment: If it helps anyone debugging, I get the same issue for PDFs with producer "Skia/PDF m86"

Answer (score 12):

It looks like some font/text combos make the text unreadable by PyPDF2, PyPDF3 or PyPDF4.

To extract the text from these PDFs, you can use the dedicated PDF text extraction package [pdfminer.six](https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six).

```
from pdfminer import high_level

local_pdf_filename = "/path/to/pdf/you_want_to_extract_text_from.pdf"
pages = [0] # just the first page

extracted_text = high_level.extract_text(local_pdf_filename, "", pages)
print(extracted_text)
```

It works on all the pdfs that were failing for me and is super quick to implement as a fallback. Full [docs for the extract_text](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/highlevel.html#api-extract-text) function are [here](https://pdfminersix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/highlevel.html#api-extract-text).