# Error: cannot import name 'PDFDocument' from 'pdfminer.pdfparser'

Tags: python-3.x, pdfminer

I need to extract text from pdf-files and have used pdfminer.six with success, extracting both text paragraphs and tables. But now I get an error related to the line

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser, PDFDocument:
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'PDFDocument' from 'pdfminer.pdfparser' (C:\Users[username]\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pdfminer\pdfparser.py)

I'm using Anaconda Jupyter. Python 3.7.3. Package pdfminer.six-20181108

The code I'm using is based on this:
[How to read pdf file using pdfminer3k?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024697/how-to-read-pdf-file-using-pdfminer3k)

Based on advice given below I've tried to uninstall and reinstall Anaconda and pdfminer.six and other packages several times: 
https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/issues/196
A week ago it suddenly worked, but now I get an error again.

Since I'm working on Win10 I also tried using Linux Ubuntu as described here:
https://medium.com/hugo-ferreiras-blog/using-windows-subsystem-for-linux-for-data-science-9a8e68d7610c

Same error.

Then, based on the webpage below I thought it was worth a try to split PDFparser, PDFDocument:
from

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser, PDFDocument
```

to

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
```

https://loctv.wordpress.com/2017/02/07/fix-importerror-cannot-import-name-pdfdocument-when-using-slate/
..
But that created new errors later on in the code.

The start of my code looks like this:

````
```
path = [name and path of file]
fp = open(path, 'rb')
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser, PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox, LTTextLine
```
````

I expect to be able to run the code and extract the text from the pdf-file, but the code is stopped by the error relating to PDFDocument pdfminer.pdfparser

Any advice on what I should do is much appreciated! Might it has something to do with how pdfminer.six is installed?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/issues/196

Comment: Yes, it was there I learned to reinstall to solve. But thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got help from Notodden Serit. Change this:

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser, PDFDocument
```

to:

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
```

And add parser in

```
doc = PDFDocument()
```

To:

```
doc = PDFDocument(parser)
```

And then:

```
for page in doc.get_pages():
```

To:

```
for page in PDFPage.create_pages(doc):
```

Answer (score -1):

[According to the pdfminer documentation](https://pdfminer-docs.readthedocs.io/programming.html)

```
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument`
```